# Internal Server Error while opening wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, web, server

I was trying to modify functions.php file in wordpress site. I added some lines of code and update the file. Now my site is not opening at shown Internal server error as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have also tried to remove new code and trying to update file again, but this error is still there. How to resolve this?

**Solution:**

Finally I have resolve it. The file I was trying to change functions.php, had some wrong syntax in code. I mistakenly updated the file with some wrong syntax, but I was not able to re-edit that file later on and I was not able to access to my wordpress admin panel too.
I went to my file manager and went to that particular theme and find functions.php file. I then removed that piece of code from it and issue resolved.

Comment: check error logs of php, find an error causing this and fix it.

Comment: It is showing 500 internal server error. What is this?

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, I don't have any telepathic powers. There are a lot of possible reasons for this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try, if you have the ability to ftp, rename the htaccess file to something like htaccess_bak, to see if that fixes it. Normally if that file gets corrupted, it will show that message